# Deprecated text style UILabel swift3

Tags: ios, swift

How to write text that have a line above it?
 [image]

The problem i don't know how to search on that
i don't know what that called

Comment: `NSAttributedString` + `NSStrikethroughStyleAttributeName`

Comment: This is a reasonable question. If you don't know the name "Strikethrough" then you won't be able to figure out how to get this text style.